# How to create a type from another type that has a specific property with diffente type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have this type:

```js
type Period = 'Monthly' | 'Yearly'
type Cycle = {
    period: Period,
    price: number
}
```

And I want to get the following type (basically, allow period to be an empty string):

```js
type Period = 'Monthly' | 'Yearly'
type EditableCycle = {
    period: Period | '',
    price: number
}
```

I was thinking about something like this made up syntax:

```js
type EditableCycle = Extend<Cycle, { period: '' }>
```

How can I achieve it?

The reason, I want the user to be able to don't choose any period when editing (hence period can be an empty string) but after validating it I'm sure period will hold a valid Period.

> note: the real type is much more complicated than Cycle, involving arrays and similar stuff, this is a cut down example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Omit` utility type to override the `period` field:

```
type Period = 'Monthly' | 'Yearly'
type Cycle = {
    period: Period,
    price: number
}

type EditableCycle = Omit<Cycle, "period"> & {
  period: Period | ''
}

const editableCycle: EditableCycle = {
  period: '',
  price: 5
}
```

If this solution works for you, you can go one step further and create your own `Override` type like this:

```
type Period = 'Monthly' | 'Yearly'
type Cycle = {
    period: Period,
    price: number
}

type Override<T, K> = Omit<T, keyof K> & K

type EditableCycle = Override<Cycle, {
  period: Period | ''
}>

const editableCycle: EditableCycle = {
  period: '',
  price: 5
}
```

I hope you find this answer helpful.

François

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to type the `Extend` utility in your question (I've renamed it to `UnifyProps` because it produces a new type including all properties in both parameters, creating a union of the types of properties with shared names):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=22&ssc=75&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwGYgAoCcD2YDOAeAFQEYAaKAgJgD4oBeKAbwCgooBtAaSgTigGsIITEnJEAugC4oXCAA9gEOABMc-QcPIUoAfigAKYpzFQAPpqMBKKFMMcxAbiYBfKADJGLdlx5qhIypLSUHIKyqoCfqI6+rbGZpSW1uZ2jk6OTKCQUKgQ6AiYSnRQAOQAsphwwAAWADYgxaYlAJoQAIbodcXpmdAAwiAAxjXQ9MyskHkFUjmTSo7jeQMQUnAArgC2AEa5qd3g0ACiSgjArZvD-UMjsIgoGNj4l8NkDFAT+UpSxQ1OVOlKECG7WgAwqOGAwQGUiOJzOF0Gw0cgIAdO8CkUyhVqp17FAAPR4qCYPhMFFowr0Yotdo4-GE4mkgao3IfDFdOlEklklnoymtOCYaq5KDgvJwADm7LxAComAA9BWKxVMAj7EoAIn5gqqwtFPHF6oaCFUAohrRwOAQ4rgcOgwEwUB6GvVjRmH2KyP0FAAzBQKFZpXimEA)

```ts
type UnifyProps<T1, T2> = {
  [K in keyof T1]: K extends keyof T2 ? (T1[K] | T2[K]) : T1[K];
} & {
  [K in keyof T2]: K extends keyof T1 ? (T1[K] | T2[K]) : T2[K];
};

type Period = 'Monthly' | 'Yearly';

type Cycle = {
  period: Period;
  price: number;
};

type EditableCycle = UnifyProps<Cycle, { period: '' }>;

declare const ec: EditableCycle;
ec.period = 'Monthly'; // ok
ec.period = 'Yearly'; // ok
ec.period = ''; // ok
ec.period = 'another string'; /*
^^^^^^^^^
Type '"another string"' is not assignable to type '"" | Period'. (2322) */
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can define it in the following way:

```
type Period = 'Monthly' | 'Yearly'
type Cycle = {
    period: Period,
    price: number
}

type Editable<T> =  {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string? (T[K] | '') : T[K];
};

type EditableCycle = Editable<Cycle>; // -->  period: "" | Period;
```